# How to replace a particular character at a particular position in sql

Tags: sql

Example: if `'qwer0000321'` in this i want to replace `'0'` with `'1'` which is in the 5 position

my output should be `'qwer1000321'`

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: There are always data is same format `qwer0000321`

Comment: TOAD is not a DBMS. It's a SQL client that can connect to different database products. So again: which DBMS are you using?

Comment: -:) @a_horse_with_no_name

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT STUFF('qwer0000321',5,1,'1')
```

Comment: Note that this is a product specific answer to a question with no dbms specified. (I.e ANSI SQL is assumed.)

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
UPDATE TABLE tab
   SET column = REPLACE(tab.col, 'qwer0', 'qwer1')
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to say which dbms are using, however for example if you use **sql server** you can replace the character you want with STUFF function.

```
select STUFF('ABC', @n, 1, 'X') from XXX
```

where ABC is your starting string, @n indicates from which position you want to replace, 1 deletes 1 character and X insert the character in that position.

In your case is

```
select STUFF('qwer0000321', 5, 1, '1') from XXX
```

Comment: yes I know, infact  I wrote "for example if you use sql server "

Comment: Yeah, now I see that.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT STUFF('QWER0000321', 5, 1, '1')
```